# How do I "normalize" accented characters in file names inside zip in php?

Tags: php, encoding

I have many already saved zips on my linux server, and the app that manages them must extract the included files.

However, uploaders of the zips have sometimes put accented characters in file names, so when php extracts the file names I could get some name with messed encoding, expecially when the zip was created in windows.

The code that extracts the file names from the zip is:

> $zip = zip_open ( $zipFile ) ;
>
> while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
> $ArrayInternalFileNames[] = zip_entry_name ( $zip_entry );

What shoud I do with $ArrayInternalFileNames content in order not to have "messed encoding" characters? The problem is that php string functions doesn't work well with those file names because of the encoding mess.

Answer (score 1):

You could try transliterating the filenames into ASCII with [`iconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
$filename = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

Comment: it doesn't work: it cuts the string at the first non correctly encoded character. Actually the "bad" string _isn't_ utf8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sammitch's answer.

Another transliteration alternative:

```
$file_name=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your source name is in UTF-8. Then:

```
$file_name=iconv("UTF-8", "IBM850", $file_name);
```

Filenames inside the zip must be `IBM850` encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
mb_convert_encoding($zip_entry, 'UTF-8');
```

That will remove any unwanted characters. Otherwise take a look at [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr) which will allow you to translate one set of characters to another.

Comment: the instruction `mb_convert_encoding($InsidedocName, 'UTF-8');` with "La vita eterna � dono di Dio lo vedremo cos� come Egli �.doc" produces "La vita eterna dono di Dio lo vedremo cos come Egli .doc"...

produces

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you wanted. Isn't it?

Comment: No, I want to get "La vita eterna e dono di Dio lo vedremo cosi come Egli e.doc